# macOS Sierra is downloaded but can't install

Tags: macos

I have downloaded the macOS Sierra from app store but unable to install it. It's not displayed in updates section...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Did you look in your applications folder? Usually it downloads there. If you open your **Applications folder** there's an app called **Install macOS Sierra**

Found at:  https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/53qqnp/macos_sierra_downloaded_but_not_installed/

Comment: @grgarside Wasn't aware that quoting was 'illegal' :) Thanks though! edit: oh, now I notice: you prettified it for all of us. Thanks again!

Comment: If you have moved it to another folder it will be updated there if you choose to download it from the App Store again. It will not be downloaded to the /Applications folder a second time.

I usually move my OS X installers to another disk and I have encountered this several times.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I had the same issue go to applications and click the file that was downloaed. It is working now as in the past it froze on me.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading macOS Sierra it doesn't appear in the Updates section of the App Store app. Instead it is downloaded to your disk and usually can be found in /Applications. If you have downloaded a public beta or a developer beta and moved it to a different folder previously, it may reside there instead.

Depending on your system language the name is *Install macOS Sierra* (English) or a name translated to your language accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the applications folder

Answer (score 0):

or just do a spotlight search for sierra

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: This worked great for me.  Not quite sure what the previous commenter found wrong with the answer.